# 18.04 upgrade from 17.10, now no sound & touchpad problem R click

Tags: sound, hp-touchpad

I upgraded from 17.10 to 18.04, and I have 2 issues....

1) I have no sound. sound output shows "speakers - Built in audio" however on testing right and left there is no sound. sound volume is turned up and not muted.

2) **SOLVED**...My touchpad has no RIGHT click option.. when testing the mouse in the Settings>Devices.. I can test my clicks and scrolling, but everytime i hit the R button on the touchpad it shows it as a primary click.

When I use my USB live CD, and try Ubuntu, my sound and touchpad work correctly. I reinstalled (wipe, install 18.04) and issue not resolved.

HP Omen laptop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I downloaded the gnome tweaks and it fixed the touchpad problem.

Open Ubuntu software (orange briefcase) and type in the search "gnome tweaks".. launch the program and under keyboard and mouse tab>Mouse click emulation> choose AREA..click bottom right.....
[image]